# Error #1064 MySQL Something is wrong in your syntax near '' accesslogh '

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I got this MySQL error 1064:

```
# 1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax near '' accesslogh '(
id INT (30) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
nam ... 'on line 1
```

When i ran

```
CREATE TABLE 'accesslogh' (
id INT(30) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
name VARCHAR(255), 
result VARCHAR(255), 
type VARCHAR(255), 
code VARCHAR(255), 
epoch INT(30), 
timestamp DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

I know it is a syntax error but I have tried to solve it following the correct theory but I can't solve it.

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql it will help you in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove quotes around table name.

```sql
CREATE TABLE accesslogh (
id INT(30) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
name VARCHAR(255), 
result VARCHAR(255), 
type VARCHAR(255), 
code VARCHAR(255), 
epoch INT(30), 
timestamp DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the backtick `` ` `` with the single quote `'`. In SQL the single quote is used for string literals, in specifically MySQL the backtick is used to denote a quoted identifier, to allow you to use special characters, white space and reserved words for identifiers. What you probably intended to do was this:

```
CREATE TABLE `accesslogh` (
id INT(30) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
name VARCHAR(255), 
result VARCHAR(255), 
type VARCHAR(255), 
code VARCHAR(255), 
epoch INT(30), 
timestamp DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

While it's not needed for your example it's a good practice to get into if your queries are going to be generated in some other code.

---

This really only applies to MySQL, other SQL DBMS tend to use square brackets `[ ]` to enclose identifiers that use reserved words or characters not otherwise allowed.